# Does SFDC Sync object create contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

When we initially establish connector and sync object like contact and lead does they create a  subscriber/contact in marketing cloud instantly or they will be only created as contact/subscriber when email or sms is sent to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you synchronise the Lead and Contact objects the records contained in your Synchronised Data Extensions automatically create Marketing Cloud Contacts that count towards your billable quota. When you send an email to a Lead/Contact or you import them into a List, they become a Subscriber.

Comment: Thanks @Macca..

Comment: One quick question, if I have a contacts in a data extension and that DE I am using as suppression list and none of those emails exsist in all subscribers or contacts, at the time of email send, will marketing cloud going to add them as contact or subscriber (with status as unsubscribeed)

Comment: No. If they're suppressed, they don't get added to All Subscribers.

Comment: Right they dont get to add in all subscribers and not in contacts also? Right?

Comment: Correct. Unless you add the records to some sort of "Population", like the explicit ones you can define in Contact Builder or the implicit ones like All Subscribers, Mobile Contacts or synced DEs, their records are just data and don't constitute billable contact records.

Comment: Thanks again Macca. It's very helpful.